# Other direction for another characterization of compactness proof

Tags: general-topology

I posted a proof of a theorem for one direction of this proposition and then successfully completed the proof, but I am having quite some trouble attempting to figure out the converse direction.

Prove:If a space $X$ is compact, then for any open set $U$ in $X$ and any collection of closed sets $\{K_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \lambda}$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}K_\alpha\subset U$ there exists a finite number of the $K_\alpha$'s whose intersection lies in $U$.

Theorem: A space $X$ is compact if and only if every collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property has a nonempty intersection.

I obtained a hint from a user which said to prove this direction, I need to apply the contrapositive and use the set $\{K_\alpha-U|\alpha \in \lambda\}$. A collection of closed subsets of $X$. I know the contrapositive to the theorem would be If there is a collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property that has an empty intersection, then $X$ is not compact. So I am thinking about showing $\{K_\alpha-U|\alpha \in \lambda\}$ is a collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property and an empty intersection. I believe I will need to use a bit of basic set theory algebra to accomplish this, which I am not one hundred percent sure about.

Attempt: So I am running into some trouble here. I want to use the subset relation  $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}K_\alpha\subset U$, to show that $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}(K_\alpha- U)=\varnothing$ and for any finite subcollection of $\{K_\alpha\}$, $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{n}(K_{\alpha_i}- U)\neq \varnothing$.

Using elementary set theory I know that $U-\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}K_\alpha=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}(U-K_\alpha)\supset \varnothing$ would this imply $\bigcap\limits_{\alpha \in \lambda}(K_\alpha-U)\subset \varnothing$? If so the first part of the proof is done. If not, what other approach can I use to show this?  Sorry, my elementary set theory is not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you have a family $\{K_\alpha:\alpha\in\lambda\}$ of closed sets such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}K_\alpha\subseteq U$, where $U$ is open. For $\alpha\in\lambda$ let $H_\alpha=K_\alpha\setminus U$; each $H_\alpha$ is closed, and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}H_\alpha=\varnothing$. $X$ is compact, so it follows from the theorem that you quote that $\{H_\alpha:\alpha\in\lambda\}$ cannot have the finite intersection property. That is, there must be a finite $F\subseteq\lambda$ such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}H_\alpha=\varnothing$. What does this say about $\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}K_\alpha$?

Comment: $ \cap K_\alpha \subset U$?

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: Yes, exactly.

Comment: How did you derive the fact that $\cap H_\alpha=\varnothing$?

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: That follows from the fact that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}K_\alpha\subseteq U$: no point of $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}H_\alpha$ can be in $U$, since the sets $H_\alpha$ are disjoint from $U$, and $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}H_\alpha\subseteq\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}K_\alpha\subseteq U$, so there can’t be any points in $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\lambda}H_\alpha$ at all.

Comment: Sorry for my lame attempt to solve the problem, I bet that's why you ignored everything I had to say from my last post. You determining my understanding of this direction of the problem was absolutely non existent. I understand. But thanks for helping me out again

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: No, I was simply very rushed at that point this evening and figured that a quick answer was better than nothing. I apologize for not having been able then to take the time to address what you actually wrote.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it.

Comment: @DanielSchmidt: You’re welcome.